# pulling stringvalue

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I would like to have a regex function that is able to pull the xxx value => **5ed4b27908106a000ee0c501** and nothing else. Any bigquery gurus in the crowd - much much appreciated!

{'system_ID': '5ed0cd139c99000f15e70','xxx': '**5ed4b27908106a000ee0c501**'}}

I would really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(str, r"'rafIn': '(.*?)'")
```

So, if to apply to example str in your question

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT("{'system_ID': '5ed0cd139c99000f15e70','rafIn': '5ed4b27908106a000ee0c501'}}", r"'rafIn': '(.*?)'")
```

result is

```
5ed4b27908106a000ee0c501
```